# generate random number on page load and store in a hidden form field

Tags: javascript

I need to generate a random number on every web page load and store that number in a hidden form field (id="field10"). Following is my code but its wrong.
Quick help is highly appreciated.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function test(final){
var min = 1;
var max = 9999999999;
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
var timeNow = new Date().getTime(); 
var final = num+'_'+timeNow;
document.getElementById('field10').value=test(final);
  }
window.onload = test;
</script>
```

Comment: The `final` is useless.

Comment: Just use id.value = final. Not test(final)

Answer (score 2):

Lot of issues. Will give a quicker solution:

```js
function test() {
  var min = 1;
  var max = 9999999999;
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
  document.getElementById('field10').value = num + '_' + timeNow;
}
window.onload = test;
```

I just removed few lines, which are unnecessary. This will work well. A glimpse of what I have done:

- Removed all the parameters.
- Removed the `final` variable (might cause troubles sometimes).
- Directly set the `value` to the element.
- Beautified the code.

**Snippet**

```js
function test() {
  var min = 1;
  var max = 9999999999;
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
  document.getElementById('field10').value = num + '_' + timeNow;
}
window.onload = test;
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(document.getElementById('field10').value);
}, 500);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="field10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, always put your scripts just before your closing `body` tag. You will not need to do the `window.onload` thing if you follow this as the DOM will already be loaded by then. Though `window.onload` might be necessary in some cases.

```js
function randomNumber() {
    var min = 1;
    var max = 9999999999;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

document.getElementById('field10').value = randomNumber() + new Date().getTime();
```

```html
<!-- add type="hidden", i omitted here so you can see the results -->
<input id="field10">
```

Comment: `final` is undefined. Dude, seriously. Think before answering. Also document what you have done. You have such a huge reputation and you are spoiling it by answering substandard answers.

Comment: yup, just noticed what he actually wants. updating the answer